# Is there some theory of SVMs with infinitely many data?

Tags: svm, generative-models

I am trying to understand what does it means to have a (linear) SVM  classifier (with soft margins) given the generative model of the data. And I realize I have not seen any paper on it, nor can I extend the theory by myself. At least two problems:

- the penalty term $C \sum \xi_i$ will become unbounded. There will be infinitely many finite $\xi_i$.
- there will be infinitely many restrictions $y(w.x_i - b) \ge  1-\xi_i$

Any suggestions or references?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Infinitely many data and SVMs don't work well with each other. Actually I don't know any classifier that does that... If you work in the dual the size of the Kernel matrix would go to infinity. If you work in primal you have the issues you discuss.

If by infinite data you mean an online setup, then there are some adaptations of SVMs for that case. For example in the primal you can work with [Hinge loss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss).

Comment: By infinite data, OP means the distributional assumptions underlying the model. Eg with linear regression, we assume that the response has a normal distribution with mean given by a linear combination of the predictors. This lets us prove various results regarding unbiasedness, consistency, etc as the sample size increases without limit. I'd be interested as well if there's any similar theory regarding SVMs.